# Adaptive frame (widget) size with swiftui shape

Tags: ios, swiftui, size, frame, shapes

I'd like to adapt my widget's size to the widget contents overall size. The problem is, that the standard shape (background of the widget) defaults to the available space and I don't want to hardcode the frame of it. Any suggestions e.g. using GeometryReader?

```
struct WidgetView: View {
    var body: some View {

        ZStack {

            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 40, style: .continuous)
                .foregroundColor(.gray)

            Text("TestingText")

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you wanted this

```
struct WidgetView: View {
    var body: some View {

        Text("TestingText")
           .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 40, style: .continuous)
            .foregroundColor(.gray))
    }
}
```

**Update:** I think your concern is due to large corner radius that might cut some internal content.

Here is some approach

```
struct WidgetView<V: View>: View {   // more generic view
    var content: () -> V
    var body: some View {
        content()
           .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 40, style: .continuous)
            .foregroundColor(.gray).padding(-20))  // compensation !!
    }
}
```

Testing (Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4)

```
WidgetView {
    VStack {
        Image(systemName: "car")
            .resizable().frame(width: 80, height: 80)
        Text("Some Label")
    }
}
```

Output

[image: demo]

Comment: I know this could be a possible approach for this specific example, but actually I want to reuse this view with different kinds of "top layers", not just with a single Text but with multiple Elements. I've realised that with embedding the view into a scroll view the problem gets fixed but it's not working for embedding in e.g. VStack.